# which class display property applies to div if i add both Bootstrap class 'd-lg-block' and 'd-none'

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

which class display property applies to div if I add both the Bootstrap class 'd-lg-block' and 'd-none'.

```
<div class="d-lg-block d-none"> </div>
```

Comment: They should both apply but if they are competing over an attribute (for example border) then one will cancel the other.

Comment: The div will only be displayed on screens larger than 992px - so both classes will apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes are responsive (using CSS media queries), so it depends on the screen width. `display:block` is applied on wider than 992px, and `display:none` is applied on less than 992px

Demo https://codeply.com/p/MIJ92PUKXe

Answer (score 0):

(Not an Angular question)

My best advice for simple things like this - especially with CSS - try it out in your browser. When I try it, d-lg-block wins.

They are both `!important`, so d-lg-block is probably winning due to being declared after d-none.

EDIT:

Having looked at the Bootstrap source code, .d-lg-block is declared later, so when your screen width is >= 992px, d-lg-block will always win.

Answer (score 0):

when you use d-none, this  is set as display none so don't on none screen, but when u add d-lg-block, only large screen size will display block, all others screen dimensions still display none becouse of your d-none.

Answer (score -1):

The last class has priority. So conflicting styles from `d-none` are applied.